# Exporting plots from R to a software of image editing

Tags: r, image, pdf, export, tiff

I am writing a scientific paper. I've done all the statistical analysis in R/RStudio and I exported my graphs (done with ggplot2) to pdf. Now I want to edit my article figures in Inkspace or Illustrator. But when I copy/paste or import my pdf files, images lose their quality... I've already combined plots in RStudio, but I want to edit the images (add elements, arrows, etc). What is the best way to do that? Any suggestions?

Comment: losing quality? are you sure you're using vector images (pdf, svg)? it would be best if you gave an example of your workflow

Comment: In my opinion `Inkscape` is the best. It's also free. Make sure you export from R as pdf or svg.

Comment: @AndreElrico - I never used Illustrator or Inkscape, but I'm choosing the free one. The only problem is that I need to export my images in tiff format, and i believe it is not possible in Inkscape, is it?

Comment: @rawr - Lost of quality is due to snapshot pdf and paste in Inkscape (because I am using Inkscape for the first time and I didn't know it was possible to import pdf and svg files). Is it possible to export tiff or eps images from Inkscape?

Comment: I'm not too familiar with inkscape (I use gimp), but if you're going to take a snapshopt, you might as well save as your favorite raster format (png, jpg) and use a higher resolution

Answer (score 2):

You can export your plots as .svg files, which is the native format for Inkscape. A simple example like so:

```
svg("examplefile.svg")#provide additional arguments for height, width, etc
plot(mtcars$mpg, mtcars$cyl)
dev.off()
```